# JVC 3CCD camcoder light changes during capture!

Tags: camcorder

I'm trying to record a training session at work that requires me to capture the Projector screen as the lecturer is teaching. The light on my JVC 3CCD camera keeps on changing between Orange, blue and Yellow.

Please help!
The training class starts in 1 day.
BM

Answer (score 2):

For consistent performance with any camera, you will want to disable any automatic functionality that may change with shooting conditions.  White balance, shutter speed, gain/iso and aperture should all be set manually.

If you need the auto-exposure, you may still get okay results by just setting the WB to a custom white balance (and setting the custom white balance to a grey card help up under the lighting). There would still be the risk of fluctuations in lighting level, but if the light levels actually do change during shooting, it would adjust accordingly.